# How to do a numpy roll on first n elements of an axis?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to roll only the first n elements from my numpy axis instead of all. However, I am at a loss on how to accomplish this.

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.random.rand(32,3,16,16)
#Foo is a batch of 32 images, with 3 channels and a height, width of 16
print("Foo Shape = ", foo.shape)
#Foo Shape =  (32, 3, 16, 16)
```

I would like to roll each first element of the second axis by 1 step. Basically roll the first channel of each image by 1.

```
np.roll(foo, 1, 1)
```

The code above rolls all the elements of the second axis (channel dimension) by 1, instead of just rolling the first element. I couldn't find any numpy functionality that helps with this issue.

Comment: Would be helpful to have an example of what is your desired output and how it differs from what numpy gives. The behavior of `roll` **is** to move all elements along an axis. Are you trying to do a horizontal roll instead of a vertical roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only the elements you want using a 2D slice:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
>>> print(arr)
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]
>>> arr[:, 0] = np.roll(arr[:, 0], shift=1, axis=1)
>>> print(arr)
[[[2 1]
  [3 4]]

 [[6 5]
  [7 8]]]
>>>
```